# When does IBM mq commits a message when we read messages through @JMSListener annotation

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am listening to the queue in my application like this

```
 @JmsListener(containerFactory = "MessageListener", destination = "${mq.destination-name}")
```

My connection factory Bean looks like this

```
@Bean(name = "MessageListener")
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> mqMessageListenerContainer(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, QueueErrorHandler QueueErrorHandler)
    {
        SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory simpleJmsListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        simpleJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        simpleJmsListenerContainerFactory.setErrorHandler(QueueErrorHandler);
        return simpleJmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }
```

I want to understand when I don't have

```
simpleJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
simpleJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

these set in factory configuration when is my application starts a transaction on reading a message and when does it commits ?

Comment: Since you have set session as trnasacted, commit method must be explicitly called. AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE has no effect as session is transacted. It is valid only for non-transacted sessions.

Comment: I haven't set the session as transacted. I don't have this line in my code simpleJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);